# Postman - How to embed a file as base64 string in a POST multipart/form-data request?

Tags: postman, multipartform-data

I would like to share my Postman-Collection including a `multipart/form-data` request with a very specific file so everything is contained within the Postman-Collection itself.

I tried several approaches like setting the value to text and adding the picture in base64 format and setting the `content-type` to `image/jpeg;base64` or prefixing the value with `base64,<base64encodedString>` and several combinations that I could think of, but to no avail.

The only documentation/hint I found was setting a postman variable that contains a dynamic definition of where the file is located - this does not solve my problem here though.

How do I embed a file within a Postman `multipart/form-data` request?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman multiform you can upload a file by hovering over the field and selecting type as file.

**Example :**

change type to file from text. Also enable the column content-type ( it will be generated automatically you don't have to chagne anything)

[image]

**Other examples:**

https://apidocs.imgur.com/

The above has a demo endpoint shows how to upload a image.