# Send JSON with image file in Postman

Tags: java, spring, http, postman

I want send a JSON file with an image in postman and I get the following error:

> "status": 415,
> "error": "Unsupported Media Type",

#### ExpertController

```java
package com.shayanr.HomeServiceSpring.controller;

import com.shayanr.HomeServiceSpring.entity.users.Expert;
import com.shayanr.HomeServiceSpring.service.ExpertService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/expert")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpertController {
    private ExpertService expertService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public void register(@RequestBody Expert expert,
            @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        expertService.signUp(expert, image);
    }
}
```

#### ExpertService

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public Expert signUp(Expert expert, MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
    if (expert == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("null expert");
    }
    if (!Validate.nameValidation(expert.getFirstName()) ||
            !Validate.nameValidation(expert.getLastName()) ||
            !Validate.emailValidation(expert.getEmail()) ||
            !Validate.passwordValidation(expert.getPassword())) {
        throw new PersistenceException("wrong validation");
    }
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(image.getName());
    if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("video") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")) {
        throw new PersistenceException("Invalid image format. Only image files are allowed.");
    }
    expert.setConfirmation(Confirmation.NEW);

    byte[] imageInbytes = image.getBytes();
    expert.setImage(imageInbytes);
    expertRepository.save(expert);
    return expert;

}
```

in postman my first row is json and this json file

```json
{
  "firstName": "Sasa",
  "lastName": "Weel",
  "email": "sasa@gmail.com",
  "password": "Sasasd1@",
  "signUpDate": "2024-01-31",
  "signUpTime": "10:00:00"
}
```

and in second row i set image  where is the problem

Comment: Please go through this link which might help-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022456/postman-how-to-embed-a-file-as-base64-string-in-a-post-multipart-form-data-req

Comment: nope still same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image` parameter looks correct.

So the next thing you should do is make sure you tell Spring that you want to allow multi-part files.

Here is a sample `application.properties` configuration:

```bash
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

Other configurations settings to control upload size:

```bash
# Adjust these file size restrictions and location as nessessary
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.location=/temp
```

I doubt that the `@RequestBody Expert expert` parameter should have anything to do with this.

Comment: i added spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true but still same error